# Why is the universal cover of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ a line bundle over $\mathbb{H}^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

In Peter Scott's "The geometry of 3-manifolds" he says that: "As $U\mathbb{H}^2$ is a circle bundle over $\mathbb{H}^2$, we see that $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$ is naturally a line bundle over $\mathbb{H}^2$"

$U\mathbb{H}^2$ is the unit tangent bundle of $\mathbb{H}^2$ and previously he shows that $U\mathbb{H}^2$ induces a metric on $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$.

Comment: What is your definition of a line bundle? If you only require smooth fiber transition maps then it suffices to note that the universal cover of the circle is a line. If you require linear transition maps then there is a line bundle structure, but not a natural one.

Comment: Yes it should be smooth so in this case the fiber in the universal cover is the universal cover of the fiber? (and similarly for the base manifold in this case the universal cover of $H^2$ is $H^2$)?

Comment: Right: Smoothly, $UH^2$ is a trivial bundle, $H^2\times S^1$, so its universal cover is $H^2\times R$.

Comment: Got it, thank you!